# How to split CSV table over 2 pages?

Tags: longtable, csvsimple

I have options of various length, so sometimes they go over the page. Is there an option on csvreader to split pages, similar to `longtable`?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%%% select the required data %%%%
% select hospital name
\newcommand{\hospital} {Hospital} 

%Pricelist name
\newcommand{\pricelist}{RFD_MTSV}

%%%%%%% DON'T ALTER FROM HERE ONWARDS (except spacing and layout)%%%%
\newcommand{\system}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{2=\sys}{\sys}}
\newcommand\systemf{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{2=\sys}{\edef\MySystem{\sys}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}       %% allow graphics

\usepackage{xcolor}                   %% allow colour
\definecolor{teal}{RGB}{76,177,155}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.4}

\usepackage[textwidth=450pt, textheight=680pt,top=3cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry} %margins

\usepackage{fancyhdr}       %% allow header, footer
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{1 cm}
\fancyfootoffset{1 cm}
\lhead{\textcolor{teal} {\monthyeardate\today}}
\chead{\textcolor{light-gray}{\hospital \, (System)}}
\rhead{\textcolor{light-gray} {page \thepage}}
\lfoot{\textcolor{light-gray} {38 years }}
\rfoot{\bfseries \textcolor{light-gray} {Company}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% first page different
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lfoot{\textcolor{light-gray} {38 years}}
    \rfoot{\bfseries \textcolor{light-gray} {Company}}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}


\usepackage{datetime} % dates - my altered dates below
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} %just month written and Year

\newdateformat{normal}{%
  \longdate \ordinaldate{\THEDAY} \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} %normal date

\newcommand\twodigits[1] {\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi}
\newdateformat{quoteNo}{%
   \THEYEAR--\twodigits{\THEMONTH}--\twodigits{\THEDAY} } % digit date for quote no.

\usepackage{fontawesome} % phone symbols
\usepackage{marvosym} % LinkedIn and Facebook symbols

\usepackage{hyperref} %hyperlinks

\usepackage{tabularx} % for the table format
\newcommand\mce{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}
\newcounter{RowNum}
\usepackage{siunitx} %counting row numbers

\usepackage{advdate} % quote expiry

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % don't hyphenate

\usepackage{csvsimple} % read Excel tables
\newcommand{\excel} {\pricelist.csv}
\newcommand{\comma}{, }
\newcommand{\commano}{,}
\newcommand{\nc}{&}
\newcommand{\ns}{\,}

\usepackage{enumitem} % dot points with indent
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \itemize[leftmargin=!,labelindent=5pt,itemindent=-10pt]
}{%
    \enditemize
}

\usepackage{longtable} %table over 2 pages

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\color{light-gray}{%
\subsubsection*{\underline{OPTIONAL ITEMS AVAILABLE}}
\vspace{0.4cm} % adjust spacing here

%\begin{longtable} %doesn't work
\csvreader[tabular = >{\stepcounter{RowNum}\theRowNum}r >{\everypar{\hangindent0.7cm}}p{12cm} b{1.3cm}, filter ifthen=\equal{\csvcolii}{1}]{\excel}{17=\dbo, 18=\deo, 15=\pricel,16=\pricer}{& \textbf{\dbo} \deo & \mce  \\ 
\mce   && \$  \hfill \ifthenelse{\equal{\pricel}{0}}{}{\pricel,}\pricer \\ \mce}
%\end{longtable}
}
\color{black}

%\hrulefill %remove if necessary


%\vspace{-0.1cm} % adjust spacing here

\textbf{Delivery Time:} Approximately 8 weeks after placement of order\\

\textbf{Payment terms:} Full payment is required no later than 30 days from date of installation. \\
\begin{minipage}{1cm}{} \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.01cm}{\footnotesize{*}} \end{minipage}\hspace{-0.7cm}\begin{minipage}[t]{15cm} {\begin{quote} \footnotesize{Any moneys outstanding after this period will be charged at 20\,\% interest from the date of delivery.} \end{quote}}\end{minipage}\\

\textbf{GST:} Unless otherwise stated, all prices in this quote are excluding GST.\\

\textbf{Quotation expiry:}\normal{\AdvanceDate[28] \today}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me following page layout:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that a simple exchange can split pages:

```
\csvreader[longtable= >{\stepcounter{RowNum}\theRowNum}r >{\everypar{\hangindent0.7cm}}p{12cm} b{1.3cm}, filter ifthen=\equal{\csvcolii}{1}]{\excel}{17=\dbo, 18=\deo, 15=\pricel,16=\pricer}{& \textbf{\dbo} \deo & \mce  \\ 
\mce   && \$  \hfill \ifthenelse{\equal{\pricel}{0}}{}{\pricel,}\pricer \\ \mce}
```

I would love comments of how to implement headers though (not for this example), but working on another project...